# Newbe on Go - AppEngine - Deploy

Tags: go, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I'm new using App Engine, and I would appreciate if someone can clarify this doubt:

How can I be sure that AppEngine in the cloud have the correct version of go I need to have in the cloud?

I have read some articles about installing and downloading the SDK for google on my local machine (and of course, I am able to install the version I need on my machine); but once I have generated my app in Go and I want to deploy it to App Engine in the cloud, how can I be sure Google infrastructure has the correct version?

I want to install Iris Web framework as part of the stack but it requires to go vers 1.14 or superior, Google App Engine standard only provides support for Google 1.11 and 1.12+ so I think I would need to go for the Google App Engine Flexible option, if that were the case, how can I be sure it has or support the Go version I need?... Or Is there some procedure to follow to install it ?

Thanks in advance  for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Flexible environment you have the ability to pin a version rather than using the latest available/supported. In order to do that, you will have to specify in your app.yaml file the exact version you would like it to be:

```
runtime: go1.14
```

If you specify only `runtime: go` it will pull the latest release available for Go language (which seems to be 1.19).

For more information, please refer to this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/reference/app-yaml#general

Comment: I wish this would be true. Actually `runtime: go` will use the "default" version which is currently 1.11, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard environment. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/runtime) for the standard environment says:

> The Go 1.12+ runtime supports the following major versions: Go 1.12, Go 1.13, Go 1.14, Go 1.15, and Go 1.16. Your app uses the latest stable release of the version that is specified in your app.yaml file. App Engine automatically updates to new patch revisions, but will not automatically update the major version.

Here's an example version spec in app.yaml:

```
runtime: go115
```